# approximating sum of i.i.d poisson using CLT

Tags: probability-theory, approximation, central-limit-theorem

We have $$ S = \sum _{k=1} ^{n} X_{k}$$ each $X_k$~$ Poisson(1)$. I want to find $$P\{S_{100} \ge200\}$$

I first approximate $S_{100}$ to standard normal.

$$P\{\frac{S_{100} - 100}{\sqrt{100}} \ge \frac{200 - 100}{\sqrt{1} \cdot \sqrt{100}}\}$$

Which result in $$ P\{Z \ge 10\}$$

Then I find it difficult to process it...

Comment: That much is correct. That's an extremely small number that software can find, for example in Matlab normcdf(10,0,1,'Upper'). Or you could have used normcdf(200,100,sqrt(100),'Upper') in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then I find it difficult to process it...

This probability is actually (EDIT) $\approx 0$. There is no need to use tables or calculators; just observe that the range of a Standard gaussian is for 99.99% in $[-3.8;3.8]$

Comment: It's not exactly zero, but yes it is indeed very very small.

Comment: @Ian : yes, very very small. My calculator arrives at $P(Z>7)\approx 1.3\cdot10^{-12}$...